# How to upload first time made project to svn server using smart svn?

Tags: svn, smartsvn

I made an iOS project. My Boss gave me a link of SVN Sever, i.e https://abc.companyname.com/svn/Mobile/

As I opened it, I found too many existing projects. I want to make new folder and upload my local project to this SVN Server.

How can I do so, I am using Smart SVN CLIENT.

I tried Project|Import into Repository , but seeing issue, see the following three pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now after third option, what should I do, There is no existing directory with my Project Name.

Comment: There's no existing directory for your project because it's new (by your own admission). You really need to read the [Subversion Manual](http://svnbook.org/) and understand how to use the tool before you start using it.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Project|Import Into Repository**:

http://www.smartsvn.com/documentation/commands.create-module

On the **Local Directory** Page, select the path of your local project which you want to add to the repository.

On the **Repository** Page, select the repository to which the project should be imported.

On the **Location** Page, select the directory in the repository to which the project should be imported. As your project is new, you will most likely want to create a new directory (click directory toolbar button with blue star on it).

Comment: What is Repository? A local copy which is in my hard disk, or the project which in on server?

Comment: What's on your computer is the **Working Copy**. The server you're interacting with hosts the **repository**. You need to read the manual and understand these terms before you use Subversion.